# how do i link my sqlite(PDO) databse data to highcharts code

Tags: php, jquery, sqlite, pdo, highcharts

I'm trying to create line chart so i'm using highcharts and they have the code for it but i just don't know how i put my sqlite database value on it. I thought of changing the value by my self but again if the database data changes i have to do it again. so i though i will use `json_encode`

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:randvalue.sqlite');
    $sth = $db->query('SELECT revenue_value FROM company');
    $sth->execute();
    $results=$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($results);

    echo $json  
?>
```

and the result is
[image]

but the code highchart provided has a different format
[image]

the full code highchart provided http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

so how do I implement my sqlite database value on to highchart code. To be honest i have no idea what i'm saying or doing.

Comment: So why can't you map `$results` to array that conforms to format expected?

Comment: how do i do it. i'm looking at example's but they are all for MySQL example

Comment: an array is an array regardless of where the data came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this also in JS:

```
var arr = [{ "revenue_value": "2000"}, { "revenue_value": "123" }, ... ]; //get it from AJAX or from PHP directly
var data = []; 
$.each(arr, function(i, d) {
    data.push(parseFloat(d.revenue_value));  // gather values, and parse them to number
});
```

Now, add your data to your options:

```
series: [{
    data: data
}]
```

PS: Instead of using images, copy&paste your code.. ;)